# Is it possible to emulate a Virtual Directory in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a solution with two Web Application Projects.  I would like to add a virtual directory to one of the projects that points at the other.  Is this possible?

Comment: Virtual Directory is an IIS artifact. It has nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: Darin, that is a valid answer, so post it as an answer.

Comment: However, when I run them in visual studio I would like to emulate a Virtual Directory for test purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the virtual directories in your local IIS - why do you want to add the complexity of doing dynamically, keep it simple, it works. Do not spend too much time figuring out something that you'll only use for debugging/testing purposes.

Comment: I debug using the ASP.NET Development Server built into VS.  I was hoping to find a way to continue using that.

Comment: If that is what you need to do, then do the following. Right-click on the project that you are pointing your main project to, then select Properties and then the Web tab. You'll see various options in this window, find the one labeled "Specific port" and type a four digit number (i.e. 1988). From your main project, you can call this other project by using the url "http://localhost:1988/"

Also, if you need to "link" back to the main project, just do the same in the main project, specify the port.

The above will allow you to go from one application to the other while debuggin in Visual Studio.